# What camera would be best to take pictures like the ones I've listed and what software might I need?

Tags: camera-recommendation

- http://bts.ibighit.com/img/photo/f_ver/4_f_jk.jpg
- http://bts.ibighit.com/wings/img/mainphoto/8.jpg

Can you tell me what camera would get me to take photos like these?

Answer (score 4):

In theory any camera would do, in practice what gives these pictures their specific look is a carefully set up lighting:

- in the first picture the underside of the bars isn't in shadows, so there is some lighting from below
- in the second one you can see two light boxes of two different colors reflected in the eyes

So you could need a complex lighting apparatus and a camera that can control it (a flash socket as a minimum, possibly a built-in RF transmitter or a master flash).  The camera could be the cheapest part of the setup...

Answer (score 3):

Pictures like that can be taken with **pretty much any camera**, including the one you probably already own on your phone. If you don't know what it would take to do that now, buying a new camera won't help.

I'd instead suggest a book like Michael Freeman's *The Photographer's Eye* — this will get you a lot closer than a new camera would.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if a question is off-topic, why do we answer anyway?

Comment: Generally we shouldn't... In my defense, this is kind of a non-answer — I'm not giving the "what camera and software to buy" advice that was asked for.